# Start Python app from pytest and debug both test and app

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python pytest test that is first starting another Python application that I am testing, then I run the test and shutdown the app.
This all works fine, but, it will be even better if I would be able to debug both the test and the running application (currently I can debug only the test).

I am using VS Code with Python extension and it will be nice if I'll manage to get it to work with PyCharm as well.

I was wondering if there is a way to attach the active debugger to the newly created process, or maybe I should start the "app under test" using a debugger such as `debugpy`?

I know VS Code is capable of debugging multiple applications.

Comment: create a launch config with an attach to python process

Comment: That will not work for me because the app starts fast and the test is also fast - usually less than 2 seconds, so not a lot of time to attach a debugger.

Comment: @Ido Ran -In VS Code, the function of debugging python code is provided by the "Python" extension, and the debugger we use it needs to configure the debugging file first, please refer to this document: [Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I can debug python code in VS Code without a problem. My question is about starting another Python application from "application under debug" and been able to debug it as well.